# deploying asp.net site on IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql, iis

Okay. Here's my problem.

I have this source code of VB.net + asp.net application which was developed on another computer. It comes with,

1. database - Microsoft sql .mdf + ita log file
2. source code of the web application

Now what I want to know is,

1. Do I need to install Microsoft SQL server to deploy this on IIS?
   (I do have Microsoft SQL server management studio express installed on my PC but the thing is I can't connect to database engine of it after installing WAMP.)
2. Do I have to copy application's database somewhere else to deploy the site?
3. What are the changes do I have to make in the code to run it properly?

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1) In order for the server to know what the database file (assuming the file is related to microsoft sql) you will need to install microsoft sql on the server.

2) The database should be fine wherever on the server as long as you know where it is.

3) This is a hard question to answer... be more specific?

Comment: Okay. First of all, does deploying on server stand for = running on my